# char * to ASN1_INTEGER

Tags: c, openssl, pki, asn.1, serial-number

For PKI certificate generation , and for setting up serial number , I used
`RAND_bytes` to get 20 bytes of random serial number, now I wanted this `char *` to be set to 
serial number of certificate , which seems to be of type `ASN1_INTEGER *`

Tried `ASN1_TYPE_set_octetstring(ASN1_TYPE *, unsigned char *, len)` but since it takes `ASN1_TYPE *` and not `ASN1_INTEGER*` it gave a crash

How do I convert between unsigned `char * to ASN1_INTEGER` ?

Thanks,

Comment: I assume you want a solution in C, so I added the "C" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is what you're looking for, but I could be wrong. If you want to have a 20-byte ASN1_INTEGER one way to do that is sending it through the BIGNUM library *first*:

```
unsigned char data[20] = {0};
RAND_bytes(data, sizeof(data));
data[0] &= 0x7F;

// build big number from our bytes
BIGNUM* bn = BN_new();
BN_bin2bn(data, sizeof(data), bn);

// build the ASN1_INTEGER from our BIGNUM
ASN1_INTEGER* asnInt = ASN1_INTEGER_new();
BN_to_ASN1_INTEGER(bn, asnInt);

// TODO: use your ASN1_INTEGER

// cleanup
ASN1_INTEGER_free(asnInt);
BN_free(bn);
```

Comment: Nice. +1 for ensuring the serial number is positive.

Comment: @jww heh. force of habit. I've honestly never used OpenSSL for this, (I use BSAFE from RSA, but the API's are similar, and i somewhat expected the sign-bit behavior would be as well =P

Comment: @WhozCraig - Oh my, BSAFE. RSA Data Securities has a serious reputation problem. First a massive data breach involving their secure id tokens, and then the NSA backdoor for money. Are you still using it?

Comment: @jww A company policy. I think we're using 4.0.1 right now, though a close review of the recent hits doesn't seem to indicate we're using the suspect features (well, at least since we stopped using their EC-based rng and started using HMAC Random, anyway).